# Adding the same field in the condition of mongodb find query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aws-documentdb

I have a mongodb collection `testdata` which contains a field called `insertTime`. We have a requirement to delete data older than 60 days. So, previously to delete older data from the collections for all documents which are older than 60 days -> I would use the following logic of first finding the deletion date and then comparing it against the updateTime:

```js
var date = new Date();
var daysToDeletion = 60;
var deletionDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysToDeletion));
deletionDate = deletionDate.toISOString()
printjson(insertDate);

db.testdata.find({"insertTime":{ $lt: deletionDate}})
```

However now, I would like to delete the data which is older than the `alive` time of the record. Alive time would be calculated as the insertTime + endTime(60 days). Now the documents older than this alive time - 60 days should be deleted. Can someone help me achieve this?

All i can think of is something like this but i don't think the command is right:

```js
db.testdata.find({"insertTime"+endTime:{ $lt: deletionDate}})
```

How do i achieve this in mongodb find command query? Please can insights be provided on this.
Thanks a ton.

I have added all the details above and what i would like to achieve.

EDIT: using AWS documentDB 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I think this `$expr` can help you:

```
var date = new Date();
var daysToDeletion = 60;
var deletionDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysToDeletion));

db.testdata.deleteMany({
    $expr: {
        $lt: [{ $add: ["$insertTime", "$endTime"] }, deletionDate]
    }
});
```

Edit:
With compatible solution with documentdb:

```
var date = new Date();
var daysToDeletion = 60;
var deletionDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysToDeletion));

db.testdata.find(
    {
        $lt: {
            $add: [
                "$insertTime",
                { $multiply: [daysToDeletion, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000] }
            ]
        },
        deletionDate
    }
);
```

Edit 2: The solution above wasn't working properly.

This one a little bit tricky but it works

```
const date = new Date();
const daysToDeletion = 60;
const deletionDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysToDeletion));
const aliveTime = { $add: ["$insertTime", "$endTime"] };

db.testdata.deleteMany({
  $and: [
    { aliveTime: { $lt: deletionDate } },
    { insertTime: { $lt: deletionDate } }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Murat. This looks like what i want to achieve but when i run this command on my mongodb documentdb terminal - i get a 303 error saying `"errmsg" : "Feature not supported"`. We are using mongodb 4.0.0 version. Is there any restriction? thanks for your help. Would appreciate inputs on this error or any alternative.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html as per this doc, $expr is not supported for mongodb documentdb. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @coding_newbie I added another solution. Couldn't fully test it but I think this will work

Comment: Thanks @Murat but i am getting the error `"errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $lt"` tried searching on this online but no luck. Any clue?

Comment: @coding_newbie Sorry for that. Now I have an another solution. I hope it will work this time :)

Comment: Hi @murat. you are too kind. Thanks. However, insertTime is different for every record in testdata collection. Can this not be added in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$dateAdd`(available from MongoDB v5.0+) to compute the alive date and compare to `$$NOW`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $lt: [
      {
        "$dateAdd": {
          "startDate": "$insertTime",
          "unit": "day",
          "amount": 60
        }
      },
      "$$NOW"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NK1H5cAXxTE)

---

Here is a version for MongoDB / AWS DocumentDB(v4.0) that OP is using. The idea is to compute 60 days late by adding 60 day * 24 hours * 60 min * 60 sec * 1000 ms = 5184000000.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      flag: {
        $lt: [
          {
            $add: [
              "$insertTime",
              5184000000
            ]
          },
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      flag: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "flag"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M4s6z0ZIHrx)

Comment: Thanks @ray  . This looks like the perfect answer to my use case BUT we are using mongodb on amazon documentdb which is only 4.0.0 compatible. Is there any alternative command or method to achieve this in a similar way?

Comment: Thanks @ray but documentdb also doesn't support $expr :(

Comment: @coding_newbie updated to a more tedious version which should work in DocDB v4.0

Comment: You are very kind ray to update it. I tested this on your mongo playground link and it works. But when i run the above command on my doc db terminal, it throws the error `"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$unset'",`. Any idea on this? Second question, can "$$NOW" in your code be replaced by `deletionDate` from my original snippet. Basically data should be deleted before the deletionDate(which is 60 days before today). Thanks

Comment: @coding_newbie oh, I thought `$unset` is supported per [this docdb doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html). Actually, it is optional since it is just removing the field `flag` that we created for checking the date. `$$NOW` is just an internal variable in MongoDB to let you refer to the current date. You should be able to replace it with equivalent in javascript.

Comment: thanks. I will check on this and get back to you to confirm if this works. Sorry, busy with other project deadlines.